# When is opacity 0 *not* transparent?

Tags: javascript, svg

I've got a curious problem (and a fix) where I draw a zero-opacity rectangle (for mouse events), but it's not transparent. It has been transparent in the past, but I've changed something in the code, and it's no longer transparent. This is the rectangle:

```
shape = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "x",      x);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "y",      y);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "width",  w);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "height", h);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "none");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke_width", 0);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill_opacity", 0);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke_opacity", 0);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke_dasharray", 0);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "#ffffff");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseover", "popup_on(evt)");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout",  "popup_off(evt)");
svgDocument.documentElement.appendChild(shape);
```

I changed something - I'm not sure what - and the box is no longer transparent - it completely obscures the background grid lines. I googled this, and tried changing the fill colour, with no change. Eventually, I found Mozilla MDN examples which used a fill of "transparent". This works in both Chrome and FF (not tried IE9).

"transparent" isn't documented as a  value in the SVG 1.1 2nd edn spec. Any ideas what's going on here? Is there something unusual about the rect above?

Comment: Look in your version control revision history, and find out what you changed.

Comment: No history. Only wrote the code an hour ago.. :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The entire code-writing/editing cycle had only been in progress for one hour, so version control wasn't relevant.

Comment: It's completely relevant, as evidenced by the fact that this question exists. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't those SVG attributes contain dashes instead of underscores (i.e. `fill-opacity`)?

Comment: Thanks! Fixed. Curious that Chrome didn't say anything.